# How can I reaction or share post with api

Tags: python, facebook

Is there any way to reaction on a facebook post or share it with facebook sdk module in python?

This is the way what i'm using to like the post, but I want another reaction instead of `like`

```
   graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
   graph.put_like(object_id=str(id))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to post reactions, and it is not clear if this will be added in the future. See documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/object/reactions)

Comment: I'd suggest you read through the documentation I linked. There does not appear to be a way to share posts at first glance.